# json curl to varible in bash

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have a CURL on my sh script.
I need save it`s ddecoded ata.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/ | python -m json.tool
```

how to save data in the varible?

Comment: `json.tool` doesn't change the output into JSON -- if json.tool accepts it as input, it's already JSON to start with.

Comment: okay. Both options work. How then can i refer to a specific element of this json?

Comment: You'd use `jq` for that. We already have lots of questions and answers in the knowledgebase describing how to do so; please search before you ask.

Comment: I'm bad in English. Please help me find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
VAR=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/ | python -m json.tool)
echo "${VAR}"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thank you for using proper code formatting and providing a link to authoritative documentation! That said, note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the following bullet point regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of a command like this: `` var=`command` ``,
so this should work fine for you:

`` json=`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hash":"$restearterHash"}' {$host}ApiController/jsonRestarter/ | python -m json.tool` ``

Comment: `var=$(somecommand)` is the modern syntax (present in the 1991 POSIX sh standard, so present in any standard-compliant shell written or updated in more than 25 years). `$()` nests better than backticks, and backslash literals contained therein have less surprising behavior.

Comment: Also, see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center, particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", *particularly* the section requesting that one not answer questions that have been asked and answered many times before.